# How to know where exactly some data has changed on firebase? (Android Studio)

Tags: firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, arduino

I am making a project that uses firebase which has the structure explained on the image. The nodes are like this userUID->MAC_addr->Data. On the Android side i have the code shown below, as you can see when some data changes it iterates a lot, this is because i dont have the "MAC" string to use it, so when something change i have to bring all the information due that. For example, if i had 2 MAC directions and some data changed on 1 of them i would have to bring the information of the other branch too. How can i improve this?

[image]

```
reference.child(Firebase.auth.uid.toString()).addValueEventListener(object :ValueEventListener{
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                for (i in snapshot.children) {
                    //iterates on macAddresses
                    for(data in i.children){
                        //iterates on the real data
                        when(data.key){
                           "AlarmActivated"->{}
                           "AlarmOff"->{}
                           ...   
                        }
                     }
                  }
```

I have tried other ways, but all of them needs to know the entire path, i was thinking to save the data on the phone (with preferences, but i dont like that approach, i hope there is a better way)

Answer (score 0):

When you listen on a certain path, you can only get information about the direct child node of that path that was changed. There is no specific information about what lower-level properties were changed.

The typical solution for your use-case is to store the previous snapshot that you got, and then compare that property-for-property to any updates in your application code. You can either use local storage for storing the data yourself, or you can [use the built-in caching](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-disk-persistence) mechanism of the SDK to handle the storage.